# How can you read/write asm registers from an .exe using C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, executable

I want to modify the value of a register that is in a certain program.
The only problem is, I don't know how to access it. If there is a way, how do I read/write into it? (preferred language C++)

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Register have changing values while running a program (in some process). So your question is meaningless; you can't modify a register in a program. But when a program runs it does modify registers and memory.

Comment: As SoapBox said, what you want to do is usually done by debuggers. It makes sense only if you do it by stopping a specific thread at a specific location (like a breakpoint), performing your register (context) changes, and then resuming the thread. I've done similar thing only on windows, there the related API doesn't even let you to change the context of a thread without stopping it in some way.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify a particular register one time while the program is running you can do so using a debugger, such as [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/).

If you want to modify the code while the program isn't running, such that in the future when you run the program it behaves differently, you can view the Assembly using a disassembler such as [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/).  But you'll also need something that can reassemble the program with your modifications, such as [NAsm](http://www.nasm.us)

You can also attach one program to another while both are running using the OpenProcess() function in windows.  You can then read and write arbitrary values to the other process, including modifying it's code.  This is a pretty tricky thing to set up and have work properly... It's how debuggers work, which are usually pretty complex pieces of software.  Better to use an existing one than to try to write your own!

Comment: Your answer is specific to Windows (and I don't think it answers the original question by OP). On Linux things would be different.

Comment: Not that different, no matter the (protected mode) operating system you have to operate as a debugger to do this. Just the program names would be different (`gdb` for Linux for example).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you correctly you want to write a program that:

- Stops another running program at a certain address (breakpoint)
- Waits until the breakpoint is reached
- Reads the current value of a certain register
- Writes another value into that register
- Continues program execution after the breakpoint

Not using a breakpoint makes absolutely no sense because the assembly registers are used for completely different purposes in different parts of the program. So modifying an assembly register only makes sense when the other program is stopped at a specific position.

Under Windows, Win32 code (not .NET code), you may du this the following way:

- Start the other .EXE file using `CreateProcess` with the `DEBUG_PROCESS` (and maybe - what would be more safe - the `CREATE_SUSPENDED`) flag set or...
- ...use `DebugActiveProcess` to debug an already running process.
- Use `ReadProcessMemory`and `WriteProcessMemory` to replace the assembler instruction (to be correct: the byte and not the instruction) at the breakpoint address by `0xCC` (`int3`).
- If you used `CREATE_SUSPENDED` use `ResumeThread` to actually start the other .EXE file
- Call `WaitForDebugEvent` and `ContinueDebugEvent` until the breakpoint is reached. You may use `GetThreadContext` to get the location where the program is stopped.
- Replace the `int3` instruction by the original instruction using `WriteProcessMemory`
- Use `GetThreadContext` and `SetThreadContext` to modify registers. Node: After an `int3` instruction the `EIP` register must be decremented!
- Use `ContinueDebugEvent` to let the program continue
- Unfortunately your program has to wait for further debugging events of the observed EXE file and handle them (`WaitForDebugEvent` and `ContinueDebugEvent`) - even if you "just" want the program to run...

If you want to stop the program at this breakpoint multiple times it is becoming more complicated: You must set the "trace" flag in the `EFlags` register each time you continue after the breakpoint so a single-step is done; after that single step you have to replace the original assembler instruction by `int3` again.

I myself did this years ago because I wrote some inspection program for that worked similar to "strace" in Linux...

If you are using C++.NET (or C#): There is a .NET assembly that allows you doing all this but using this assembly is not easier than the Win32 variant.

If you want to do this for educational uses only:

Unfortunately the debugging API of Windows is by far less easy to use then the debugging API (`ptrace`) of Linux. If you just want to do this for educational purposes (and the EXE file you want to inspect is written by you) I would do this excercice under Linux, not under Windows. However even under Linux this is not an easy job...